# Change Textfield colour on focus ExtJs

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, focus, textfield

I'm trying to change the colour of a textfield when the user put the cursor on it, to be more easy to the user find the textfield.

I see in another post's how to change the colour with the css rules, and i found in the API, the fieldCls and focusCls to change the colours, but it isn't working, i know the problem is on the focus event that isn't fiering,

Definition of the Button:

```
xtype:'textfield',
focusCls:'red',
fieldCls:'green',
listener: {
    'focus':function(){
        Ext.Msg.Alert('Focus','TextField have focus'); //This don't run
    }
}
```

CSS rules:

```
.red {
    background-image: none;
    background-color:#ff0000 !important;
}
.green {
    background-image: none;
    background-color:#00ff00 !important;
}
```

I made this test's on fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/FabioJCosta/3ZZcZ/547/**

Even when i'm forcing the focus with a button textfield.focus(false, 200); the focus event isn't fiering.

I hope this helps another people.

Thank You

Comment: The main issue is solved thank's to Marcel, but the problem with the non working focus is still active, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery if I understand the question.

```
.green:focus {
    background-image: none;
    background-color:#ff0000 !important;
}
.green {
    background-image: none;
    background-color:#00ff00 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i don'k know much of css, so I try to use the property focusCls, of the ExtJs, but like you said isn't needed. 

This Resolves the problem, but in all cases, the ExtJs sould fire the focus event...

Comment: Thanks for the selecting me for the best answer! I can comment now!!